# openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended error phpmyadmin

Tags: ssl, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am getting this issue while opening my phpmyadmin. I haven't done anything on my server

/libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#744
openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended
Backtrace

./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#744: openssl_encrypt(
string 'userid',
string 'AES-128-CBC',
string '',
integer 0,
string '',
)
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#626: AuthenticationCookie->cookieEncrypt(
string 'userid',
string '8a782c92b7c2ca333600e3da8d629fbb',
)
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#549: AuthenticationCookie->storeUsernameCookie(string 'userid')
./libraries/common.inc.php#1037: AuthenticationCookie->storeUserCredentials()
./prefs_manage.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the certificate was not properly renewed in apache server. Although you can access MySql Db in your server using Sql Workbench for windows and Sequel pro for Mac or if you want to fix this issue in your server you can perform this command

```
sudo apache2ctl stop
```

to stop the service, and

```
sudo apache2ctl start
```

to start it again.

The certificate will be renewed and Issue will be fixed.